# $f:\mathbb R^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ s.t ${f(x,y)}={{xy}\over {x^{2}+y}}$ is not continuous at the origin

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

$f:\mathbb R^{2} \rightarrow  \mathbb R$  is  defined  as
$${f(x,y)}={{xy}\over {x^{2}+y}}$$; when  $x^{2}+y\neq 0$ and $$f(x,y)=0$$  otherwise.

To  show  this  is  not  continuous  at  the  origin .  A  hint  is  given  as  to  go  along  the  line $y=mx$ .

So  along  that  line  $$f(x,y)=f(x,mx)={{mx^{2}}\over {x^{2}+mx}}$$  $$={{mx}\over {x+m}}$$

Taking  limit  tending  to  $0$ , we  have  $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0 }f(x,y) =0=f(0,0)$$

Then  where  is  the  contradiction  to  continuity  by  moving  along  $y=mx$ $?$

Comment: Wrong hint. Try $y=x^3-x^2$.

Comment: @Did  :  Thanks  , that  works . But  tell  me   one  thing ,  how  do  I  think  of   such  paths   when  to  verify  continuity?

Comment: there is no way in general. What you have to prove is that the continuity does not depends on the path. The best approach is try by sequences limit or $\epsilon$ and $\delta.$

Comment: When, as here, you try to disprove that the limit of a ratio is zero, the task is to make the denominator extra small--thus the idea that $x^2+y=z$ with $z\ll x^2$. Now, if $y=z-x^2\sim-x^2$ then the numerator is $xy\sim-x^3$ hence $z\gg x^3$ is forbidden but $z=|x|^a$ works, for every $a\geqslant3$.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the hint is helpful at all here. The main problem is that the function's values blow-up around the curve $\{y=-x^2\}$, which passes through any neighborhood of the origin.

To be explicit, for any $0<\delta<1$, the point $(\delta, -\delta^2)$ is in the $2\delta$-disk neighborhood centered at the origin. Furthermore, for small $\eta > 0$ the point $P_\eta = (\delta, -(1+\eta)\delta^2)$ is in the same disk, but not directly on the curve $\{y = -x^2\}$.

We have that
$$ f(P_\delta) = \frac{1+\eta}{\eta} \delta.$$
Freezing $\delta$, you can take $\eta\to 0$ to find arbitrarily large values of  $f$ on the disk $\{|\vec x\|<2\delta\}$. There is no way for the function to be continuous at the origin.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Take the curve $x^2 + y = mxy.$