# $\int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt \ge {f(x)}$ holds or not on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $$f\colon [0,1]\rightarrow [0, \infty )$$  be  continuous. Suppose that

$$\int_{0}^{x} f(t)\,\mathrm dt \ge {f(x)} \quad\text{for  all }x\in[0,1].$$

Then

$A.$ No  such  function  exists.

$B.$ There  are  infinitely  many  such  functions.

$C.$ There is  only  one  such  function

$D.$ There  are  exactly  two  functions.

Now  I  was  thinking,  since $\int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt$  is  the  area  under  the  graph  of  $f(t)$  from $0$  to  $x$ so it  can  be  easily  made  greater  than  the  value  of  $f(t)$  at  one  point, namely  $x$.  So  there   will  be  infinitely  many  such  functions  satisfying  this  condition.

Is  my  reasoning  correct or  not?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, this is not a reasoning...

Comment: If $f(t)\not\equiv 0$ satisfy the inequality then so do the function $\lambda f(t)$ for any $\lambda>0$. This rules out D.

Comment: @Winther Unless $f \equiv 0$, so that $\lambda f = f$ for every $\lambda>0$.

Comment: It is known that the derivative of a function cannot be bounded by function itself.

Comment: OP: What about correcting the mess [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1418864/)?

Comment: Hey  @Did , thanks  for  notifying  me . And  you  know what , I am  more  than  glad  to  see  you again  after  the  kind  of  love affair  we  had  last  time , :P . Jokes  apart , I  really  mean it. :)

Answer (score 17):

Your reasoning has a big hole - the condition is supposed to hold for all $x$, and you talk about just one $x$.

Say $f\le c$. Then the inequality shows that $f(x) \le cx$. Now integrate $cx$ and you see that $f(x)\le c x^2/2$. And then $f(x)\le cx^3/6$. By induction $f(x)\le cx^n/n!$. Let $n\to\infty$ and you see $f(x)=0$. So there's exactly one such function.

Answer (score 9):

Let us modify the problem slightly.

Assume that the function
$$
f:[0,a]\to[0,\infty)
$$
is continuous and that
$$
\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\, dt \ge f(x) \quad \text{for all } x\in[0,a].
$$
Then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in[0,a]$.

**Proof.** We can rewrite the inequality as
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-x}\cdot\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\, dt\right) \le 0 \quad \text{for all } x\in[0,a].
$$
Consequently the function
$$
x\mapsto e^{-x}\cdot\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\, dt
$$
is decreasing and it takes its maximum at $x=0$. 
Thus
$$
e^{-x}\cdot\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\, dt \le 0 \Leftrightarrow \int_{0}^{x}f(t)\, dt \le 0.
$$
However $f$ is non-negative and continuous. We conclude that
 $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in[0,a]$.

Comment: This is the nicest approach.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly the nicest approach. Seems curious that $e^x$ is important here, while the terms in the power series for $e^x$ come up in the solution I gave - could be that in some sense they're really the same...(?)

Comment: The function $e^{-x}$ is an integrating factor.

The given inequality could be changed to
$\displaystyle 
\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\, dt \ge g(x)f(x) \quad \text{for all } x\in[0,a],
$
where $g$ is a positive, continuous function. As before $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in[0,a]$ will be the only solution.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, I forgot
to address my comment above to you.

Answer (score 7):

Let $f$ be such a function.
If $0<x< 1$ then by the MWT, there exists $\xi\in (0,x)$ with
$$\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt=xf(\xi)\stackrel{(1)}\le x\int_0^\xi f(t)\,\mathrm dt\stackrel{(2)}\le \int_0^\xi f(t)\,\mathrm dt\stackrel{(3)}\le \int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$
We conclude that $(1)$, $(2)$,  and $(3)$ are in fact equalities.
The second means that $\int_0^\xi f(t)\,\mathrm dt=0$, the third that $\int_\xi^x f(t)\,\mathrm dt=0$, so that in fact $\int_0^x f(t)\,\mathrm dt=0$. 
As this holds for all $x\in(0,1)$ and $f$ is continuous, we conclude $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.
So, $C$ - final answer.

Comment: Of course unless I'm missing something this depends on the fact that $x\le 1$; mine would work just as well for $f:[0,2]\to[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich In fact yours would work *imediately* for any $[0,n]\to[0,\infty)$ and then per union even for $[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$. -Then again, *any* method that shows that $f$ must be $\equiv 0$ on some $[0,\epsilon]$ can be adjusted to work for $[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$: Assume $f$ is nonzero and let $a=\inf\{\,x\in[0,\infty): f(x)\ne 0\,\}$. Then apply the argument to $[a,a+\epsilon)$ ...

Comment: I don't understand your second equality. Should it be inequality (where one uses the property of $f$ given in the problem)?

Comment: i think same as mikep

Comment: @mickep Ack, I missed that - but it turns out to be an equality in the end as well by the squeezing ...